# mysql_real_escape_string not working for me

Tags: php, sql, database, mysql-real-escape-string

When I try to do a `mysql_real_escape_string` for a login system, it does not record the variable from the form. If I do

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

and echo it, it displays, but when I do

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

and echo it, it does not display. I also tested the database connections, and they work. This is my code:

```
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect($connection, $user, $pass, $database);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    echo $username;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    echo $sql;
    $result = mysqli_query($sql, $db);
```

It used to work before, but for some reason it stopped working suddenly.
Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: You have to pass connrction object..` mysql_real_escape_string($connection_object,$_POST['username']);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be escaping data to build queries. You should be using prepared statements. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

That said, your problem is that you're using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but you have a `mysqli` (not `mysql`) connection. `mysqli` and `mysql` are different extensions. Please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure - they have been removed entirely from modern versions of PHP (version 7.0 and higher). Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

To fix your problem *temporarily*, use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead of `mysql_real_escape_string()`. To fix it *permanently and correctly*, use prepared statements and not escaping.

Comment: I tried using mysqli and it still didn't work. I did `mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);` and still nothing.

Comment: @FranciscoF. Pay attention to the arguments: `string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`. The first argument, in your case, should be `$db`. So, the actual line is `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);`.

Comment: So it would be `mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username'])`?

Comment: As @EdCottrell recommended, look into prepared statements, then you won't need to use escape string.